# HttpWebResponse.StatusCode isn't trapping 500 Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httpwebrequest, yellow-screen-of-death

**My Question:**
Does a HttpWebResponse.StatusCode detect Asp.Net errors? Mainly a yellow screen of death?

**Some Background:**
I am working on a simple c# console app that will test servers and services to make sure they are still functioning properly. I assumed since the HttpStatusCodes are enumerated  with OK, Moved, InteralServerError, etc... that I could simply do the following.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = 10000;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
   // SERVER IS OK
   return false;
}
else
{
   // SERVER HAS SOME PROBLEMS
   return true;
}
```

I found out this morning however that this doesn't work. An ASP.Net application crashed showing a Yellow Screen Of Death and my application didn't seem to mind because the response.StatusCode equaled HttpStatusCode.OK.

What am I missing?

Thanks
// lance

**Update**
Thanks to Jon this seems to be working.

```
 HttpWebResponse response;
 try
 {
   response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 }
 catch (WebException webexp)
 {
   response = (HttpWebResponse)webexp.Response;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetResponse` will throw a `WebException` for errors - but you can catch the `WebException`, use [`WebException.Response`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx) to get the response, and then get the status code from that.

As far as I'm aware, `GetResponse` *never* returns null, so you can remove that test from your code.

Also, rather than having if/else blocks to return true/false, it's simple just to return the result of evaluating an expression, for example:

```
return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

(To be honest, you could probably return `false` if *any* `WebException` is thrown...)